# after hitting submit button a form will appear below the button. here "hello world" appears. i want an Input field

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

[here "hello World" appears after hitting the sibmit button.what should I do if i want an input field??](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick)

Comment: append the input using the append function:https://api.jquery.com/append/ or change the html using the html function: https://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I don't even understand what you really want to achieve. Do you want some custom content typed into some input field to show by clicking the button instead of 'hello world'?

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can create your own input field

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container")


function myFunction() {
    var input =  document.createElement("input")
    input.type="text";
    input.placeholder="Hello i am a new input"
    container.appendChild(input)

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function that will create an input field </p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```